# How do you declare a recursive mutex with POSIX threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, recursive-mutex

I am a bit confused on how to declare a recursive mutex using pthread.
What I try to do is have only one thread at a time be able to run a piece of code(including functions) but after scepticism I figured out that the use of mutexes would not work and that instead I should use recursive mutexes. Here is my code:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);                   // LOCK

item = queue_peek(queue);                     // get last item in queue
item_buff=item;                               // save item to a buffer
queue_removelast(queue);                      // remove last item from queue

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);                 // UNLOCK
```

So what I try to do is just read/remove from the queue serially.

The thing is that there isn't any example out there on how to declare recursive mutexes. Or there maybe a few but they don't compile for me.

Comment: You do not need recursive mutexes to solve this.  The example you have given is fine, as long as the same `mutex` is used for all threads that access `queue`.  For this reason, it would be usual to include the mutex within the queue itself: `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex->queue);`, or if the queue is an opaque data structure, `queue_lock(queue);` (where `queue_lock()` locks the mutex internally).

Comment: One of the gurus behind pthreads, David Butenhof, has an amusing recursive mutex rant at http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html . So yeah, recursive mutexes are usually an indication of a faulty design.

Comment: @janneb: There are many correct uses for recursive mutexes, but yes I would strongly advise a beginner against them...

Comment: @R..: I think there're not so many correct uses for recursive mutexes that cannot be redesigned to avoid them.

Comment: @AndyT: The main class of important uses for recursive mutexes that I know of is when you have operations on a shared resource that need to individually be atomic, but also want to allow grouping several operations together as an atomic transaction. The classic example is stdio with `flockfile`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The code from Michael Foukarakis is almost good but he initializes the mutex twice which leads to undefined behavior. It should just be:

```
pthread_mutex_t Mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_t Attr;

pthread_mutexattr_init(&Attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&Attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
pthread_mutex_init(&Mutex, &Attr);
```

I actually use this code in production, and I know it works correctly on Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, Mac OSX and FreeBSD.

You also need to add proper linker flag to compile this:

```
AIX, Linux, FreeBSD:
CPLATFORM += -pthread

mingw32:
LDFLAGS += -lpthread
```

Comment: Some systems require to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` (otherwise a compiler throws **implicit declaration**)

Comment: I'm getting:
`main.c:4:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 pthread_mutexattr_init(&Attr);`

Comment: This needs `pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&Attr)` at the end or else you'll be leaking memory.

Answer (score 20):

To create a recursive mutex, you can either use:

```
#include <pthread.h>
/* Don't forget to check the return value! */
int pthread_mutexattr_settype(pthread_mutexattr_t *attr,
                               int type);
```

where type is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`, or an initialiser.

For example:

```
/* ..or PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP */
pthread_mutex_t       mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutexattr_t   mta;
```

or alternatively, initialize at runtime (don't do both, it's undefined behaviour):

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mta);
/* or PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP */
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mta, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mta);
```

Comment: I get the error that I got in my earlier tries. The lines that don't compile are the three last ones and I use GCC with -pthread flag. pthread.h is also included.

Comment: Which error? You never mentioned one. Anyway, check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, which error indeed, and which OS?  Solaris requires [g]cc -mt for multithreaded applications.  A few implementations of "pthreads" are not 100% POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 18):

On Linux (but this is non portable to other systems), if the mutex is a global or static variable, you could initialize it like

```
static pthread_mutex_t recmutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```

(and by the way, the example is from `pthread_mutex_init(3)` *man* pages!)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Thus I found on MAC it is:

static pthread_mutex_t recmutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

Answer (score 2):

You need to add mutex attributes when creating the mutex.

Call `pthread_mutexattr_init`, then `pthread_mutexattr_settype` with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` then use these attributes with `pthread_mutex_init`. Read `man pthread_mutexattr_init` for more info.